# Declaring variable values

Tags: java

I'm struggling to declare vowel values in my program, We need to remove the from the users input.

```
vowels = 'a';
vowels = "A";
```

it all compiles until i attempt to add a second value!

Comment: What type is ``vowels``?

Comment: What is your actual code, what are you trying to do, and what is actually happening?

Comment: what? explane better

Comment: The first is a `char` assignment and the second is a `String` assignment.

Comment: In the first line you're setting `vowels` with a char. In the second line you're setting it with a String.  Which is it?

Comment: Can you please be more specific as to what you are trying to do? Provide more code so we can help you fix it.

Comment: I don’t believe it’s Java. Won’t compile.

Answer (score 1):

To remove all the vowels from a `String` `s`:

```
String withoutVowels = s.replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU]", "");
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the `(?i)` flag to ignore casing.